# Not show div on one specified page using shortcode

Tags: php, shortcode

I got shortcode like this:
if i want to show my div only on single specified page (WORKS):

```
add_shortcode('mydiv-01', 'mydiv_01');

function mydiv_01($a)
{
    if (trim(str_replace(URL(), '', currentUrl(0))) != T('Login-slug', 'login')) return false;
    $return .= '<div id="mydiv01">
            div content
            </div>';

    return $return;
}
```

and i want to make another div that not showing only on a single page, but so far only give me a http error 500 page.

Comment: Check your php_error.log for the specifc error.

Comment: plz, paste the code that gives your error 500, or explain better what is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the div you are showing on a single page is the login page and the one you want to show on every page but one is the login page also you could add an else clause to your conditional to achieve this.